# Autoplay on slider doesn't play after showing next div

Tags: javascript

I want to have an autoplay in my slider but I encounter a problem. After showing next div it doesn't continue to show another div.
How can I fix this?

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="mySlides active" style="background-image: url('images/1.jpg')">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides" style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg');">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides" style="background-image: url('images/3.jpg');">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var currentSlide = 1;
    var isPlaying = true;

    function nextSlide() {
        showSlide(currentSlide += 1)
    }

    function showSlide() {
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

        if (currentSlide > slides.length) {
            currentSlide = 1;
        }

        for (i = 1; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.opacity = "0";
        }

        slides[currentSlide-1].style.opacity = "1";
        slides[currentSlide-1].style.transition = "all .5s";
        // slides[slideIndex-1].setAttribute("style", "opacity: 1; transition: ease .5s;");
    }

    if (isPlaying) {
        setTimeout(nextSlide, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Multiple issues: 1.) Indexing is from `0` not `1`, 2.) `slides[currentSlide-1]` will not work as when you change `currentSlide = 0` the value will change to `-1` which will throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your provided code a bit. Here is working example:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="mySlides" style="background-image: url('images/1.jpg')">1
</div>

<div class="mySlides" style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg');">2
</div>

<div class="mySlides" style="background-image: url('images/3.jpg');">3
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var currentSlide = 1;
var isPlaying = true;

function nextSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide += 1)
}

function showSlide() {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    if (currentSlide >= slides.length) {
        currentSlide = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.opacity = "0";
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
            slides[currentSlide].style.display = "block";
    slides[currentSlide].style.opacity = "1";
    slides[currentSlide].style.transition = "all .5s";
    // slides[slideIndex-1].setAttribute("style", "opacity: 1; transition: ease .5s;");
}

if (isPlaying) {
    setInterval(nextSlide, 500);
}
```